# Segoe UI font size seems to differ between desktop and WinRT

Tags: fonts, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a probably really stupid question, but we're very confused. Our designer is making the screens for a WinRT (Win 8.1) application on Adobe Illustrator, using, as usual, Segoe UI.
Problem is that the font sizes he's using look drastically different on both a Surface Pro 3, and my own laptop where I'm developing.
It's not that it just looks bigger, that's normal, the resolutions are really different. The proportions are completely off. He has a text with Segoe UI size 52, and it takes a lot more % screen size while running as a Windows Store app than it does on Illustrator.

I figured that font sizes were different on WinRT and the desktop environment.
To test this, I ran a WinRT app, took a screenshot of a screen with a text with a certain size. Compared it against, for example MS Word, zoom 100% (so it should be "real" size), same text, same font size. It STILL looks way bigger while running on the app.

What am I missing? Shouldn't both texts look exactly the same, if the text on Word and the text on the WinRT are being displayed on the same computer, same resolution?

Example:
[image: The image above comes from MS WordPad, the second comes from a Windows Store app, both on the same computer, same resolution, both Segoe UI Light size 36]
You can see both texts having very different sizes.

Thanks!

Comment: What font measurement are you using when you specify `52`? Have you read through discussions about DPI scaling in WinRT apps? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx

Comment: No, I hadn't. So, WinRT scales, and desktops apps don't by default? That's why I'm seeing different sizes on the same machine? If that is the case, how can a visual designer figure out what the correct font sizes would be for a WinRT app?

Comment: given that WinRT has not been extended into the Windows 10 family, and the Surface Pro 1 and 2 are getting pretty old, a guess on an answer to the second half of that question could be "by not putting effort into WinRT application development anymore and moving on to developing for the current OS offering".

Comment: If you just type in 52, you're getting device independent pixels, but in Illustrator and Word, it's in points. `1 point = 1/72 inch.` The sizes need to be specified in pixels, adjusted for a standard DPI/screen.

Comment: Ok, so I take it there is no easy way to translate one to another... @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am working on a Surface Pro 3, not 1 or 2, and I do not make business decisions like that, my employer does, Windows 10 is not out yet, and this project (in WinRT, not Windows 10) was actually pitched to my current client BY MICROSOFT, so... :)